# Ubuntu 18.04.2 won't detect second monitor

Tags: drivers, 18.04, nvidia, multiple-monitors

I'm unable to get Ubuntu to detect my second monitor, which is connected via HDMI. I'm running Ubuntu 18.04.2 on Lenovo Legion Y730 with a Nvidia GeForce GTX 1050 Ti graphics card (and some Intel integrated one, too). I always have to select "Ubuntu on Wayland" on login, as if I just select "Ubuntu", I'm stuck in the login loop, which doesn't allow me to proceed past the login screen.

To address the above issues, I've tried multiple things: I've tried to install the nvidia drivers, but this only lead into [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1162594/installing-nvidia-drivers-for-lenovo-legion-y730-with-geforce-gtx-1050-ti). With nouveau drivers, I can at least boot and log in, if I select "Ubuntu on Wayland".

Below is the output of `lshw -c video`, if that would be helpful

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
       description: 3D controller
       product: GP107M [GeForce GTX 1050 Ti Mobile]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:62000000-62ffffff memory:50000000-5fffffff memory:60000000-61ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:63000000-6307ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       logical name: /dev/fb0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom fb
       configuration: depth=32 driver=i915 latency=0 mode=1920x1080 visual=truecolor xres=1920 yres=1080
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:130 memory:6022000000-6022ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:5000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```